# Before my performance was slow. Now my VirtualBox Virtual Machine saids "No Bootable Medium Found"!

Tags: boot, virtualbox

Can anybody please help me here?

A couple of days ago, I asked on this website, how to speed up performance on Ubuntu 13.04.
Now I just got a message saying "FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted. Something I did not want to see. All I did was extend a bit of memory. I made it from a iso image downloaded from ubuntu.com. Why did it fail?

Adrian,

Answer (score 0):

The virtual machine does not have a bootable virtual disk or CD-ROM ("no bootable medium found"). Open the virtual machine settings, go to the "Storage" panel, and add a live CD.

The message also appears when there is no bootable medium enabled in the Boot Order preferences of the virtual machine, but I think that this is not the case.

The live CD ejects itself from the machine (be it physical or virtual) when you shutdown it. It opens the tray and displays the message: "Please remove installation media and close the tray, then press ENTER" since it assumes that the disk has been ejected.

However, if you check the "Live CD" checkbox in the "Storage" panel, VirtualBox will retain the CD in the virtual drive.